# Invoke AngularJs method from outside without need of $digest

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

When invoking method from outside AngularJs I need to invoke $digest/$apply, but I don't want to take care of that. Is there a good way to do that?

```
<button ng-click='sayHello()'>greet</button>
{{greeting}}

//This works fine!
$scope.sayHello = function () {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello!';
};

//This needs a $digest!
$scope.sayHello = function () {
    //setTimeout simulates invokation from outside AngularJs.
    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.greeting = 'Hello!';
        //I don't want to think about $digest(); 
        //So, how to do this without the $digest?
        $scope.$digest(); //or $scope.$apply();
    }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Whats you specific case you want to work around? Is it only `setTimeout` or `setInterval` or something more complex?

Comment: @domakas It's a more complex situation. I have some (old existing) code, which invokes the AngularJs part. Unfortunately not my whole application is AngularJs.

Comment: Then you need to do what Christoph said - wrap everything in `$scope.$apply`. When you update something outside angular, it doesn't know when something changed, so you need to tell angular, that something changed and you want your model/view/etc updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific case of setTimeout you would want to use the $timeout built-in. In other cases (eg. JQuery Events) you can wrap your Code in an apply block thus lifting it into the AngularJS digest cycle like so:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    //Your Code goes here
  }
}, 1000);
```